# WPF RibbonButton: LargeImageSource and Label not updated via DataTriggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, ribbon

I'm puzzled by a peculiar phenomenon in RibbonButton's behavior.

Everything works fine when I set the LargeImageSource and the Label statically in XAML:

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="ButtonArchive"
                     LargeImageSource="..\Assets\archive_insert.png"
                     Label="{Binding Path=ItemArchiveButton, 
                     Source={StaticResource Strings}}"/>
```

But when I try to modify these properties via DataTriggers - nothing seems to be happening.
The triggers do work; I can see the other properties - like Command or IsEnabled - set OK in the same trigger. It's just these too...

Here's the XAML:

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="ButtonArchive"
    LargeImageSource="..\Assets\archive_insert.png"
    Label="{Binding Path=ItemArchiveButton, Source={StaticResource Strings}}">
    <ribbon:RibbonButton.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding ElementName=ItemsList, Path=SelectedItem.IsArchived}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonButton.Command" Value="{Binding ArchiveItemCommand}" />
                    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonButton.LargeImageSource" Value="..\Assets\archive_insert.png" />
                    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonButton.Label" Value="{Binding Path=ItemArchiveButton, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding ElementName=ItemsList, Path=SelectedItem.IsArchived}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonButton.Command" Value="{Binding RestoreItemCommand}" />
                    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonButton.LargeImageSource" Value="..\Assets\archive_extract.png" />
                    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonButton.Label" Value="{Binding Path=ItemRestoreButton, Source={StaticResource Strings}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ribbon:RibbonButton.Style>
</ribbon:RibbonButton>
```

Setting the Command works fine in the both conditions, but not the other 2 properties...

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question at the MSDN forum, and the answer I've got really solved this.

> The problem is your setting properties for LargeImageSource and Label in the button itself.  When you do this it takes precidence over your style triggers.  I suggest using setters in the style to set your defaults, and remove the property settings it the button.