# C# WPF RibbonButton Change Icon on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseover, ribbon

I have a Ribbonbutton which I want to change the Icon on MouseOver but it does not seem to work.

Here is my Code:

```
<RibbonButton Label="Verbindung testen" LargeImageSource="../Resources/Buttons/disconnect.png" Command="{Binding SettingsVM.TestConnectionCommand}">
                    <RibbonButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="../Resources/Buttons/connect.png"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="../Resources/Buttons/disconnect.png"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RibbonButton.Style>
</RibbonButton>
```

It just shows the first Icon "disconnect.png" and on mouse over it gets highlighted like all the other buttons, but no image change.

I also tried it this way, with ControlTemplate:

```
<RibbonButton Label="Verbindung testen" LargeImageSource="../Resources/Buttons/disconnect.png" Command="{Binding SettingsVM.TestConnectionCommand}">
<RibbonButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="../Resources/Buttons/connect.png"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="../Resources/Buttons/disconnect.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</RibbonButton.Template>
```

Here it doesn't show an icon at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Answer!

[WPF RibbonButton: LargeImageSource and Label not updated via DataTriggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408609/wpf-ribbonbutton-largeimagesource-and-label-not-updated-via-datatriggers)

> The problem is your setting properties for LargeImageSource and Label in the button itself. When you do this it takes precidence over your style triggers. I suggest using setters in the style to set your defaults, and remove the property settings it the button.

So it has to be:

```
<RibbonButton Label="Verbindung testen" Command="{Binding SettingsVM.TestConnectionCommand}">
<RibbonButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="../Resources/Buttons/connect.png"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="../Resources/Buttons/disconnect.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</RibbonButton.Style>
```

Removing the "LargeImageSource" from the Button itself.